# -bash: scripts/mysql_install_db: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, lamp, fedora

can someone please help.
I am trying to set install a LAMP server on Fedora 18
I kept getting an error message whenever i run the "scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql"  command.

```
-bash: scripts/mysql_install_db: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

by the way, I want my 'P' to be a PHP and not Perl
Below is how I went about the installation:
    $  groupadd mysql
    $  useradd -g msql -c "MySQL Server" mysql
    $  gzip...
    $  tar....
    $  ln ...     to create a symbolic link named (mysql)
    $  cd msql          (pwd: /usr/local/mysql/)
    $  scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql

!!!Now this is when i get that error message!!!!!!.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the scripts you are trying to execute have CR+LF EOL marker.  You can verify that by issuing:

```
file <filename>
```

(The output would contain `with CRLF line terminators`.)

Change it to `LF` and the scripts should execute fine.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline for more.

Comment: Thanks, that link was helpful. However how do i go about changing it to LF?     # file mysql_install_db
    mysql_install_db: Perl script, ASCII text executable

Comment: Try executing `dos2unix mysql_install_db` before issuing your command.  If that doesn't work, execute `bash -x scripts/mysql_install_db --user=MySQL` or whatever command and post the result?  (That would result in a verbose output.)

Comment: + use Fcntl  scripts/mysql_install_db: line 37: use: command not found
+ use File::Basename scripts/mysql_install_db: line38: use:         + use File::Copy
scripts/mysql_install_db: line 39: use:  
+ use Getopt::Long
scripts/mysql_install_db: line 40: use: +use Sys::Hostname
scripts/mysql_install_db: line 41: use:     "
+ use Data::Dumperscripts/mysql_install_db: line 42: use:
+ use strict
scripts/mysql_install_db: line 43: use:
scripts/mysql_install_db: line 45: syntax error near unexpected token `"pass_through"'scripts/mysql_install_db: line 45: `Getopt::Long::Configure("pass_through");

Comment: The command should have read `perl -w scripts/mysql_install_db --user=MySQL`

Comment: i do not have perl or any of its dependencies installed on the system. I think my best bet is to convert the file to an LF (unix executable file). as you rightly said earlier.

Comment: any suggestion on how to convert the file will be much appreciated   thanks

Comment: Execute `dos2unix mysql_install_db`.  If `dos2unix` isn't available on your system, try `sed 's/.$//' mysql_install_db > mysql_install_db.new; mv mysql_install_db.new mysql_install_db`

Comment: Also check the path to `perl` on your system (`which perl`).

Comment: thanks mate. I had to install perl as you said, also installedyum install perl
yum install perl-Data-Dumper